# Error while inserting Jar File in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, realm

I am adding jar file of realm to my android project and its giving this error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:packageAllDebugClassesForMultiDex'.
  java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: io/realm/DefaultRealmModule.class
```

My Gradle File:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    signingConfigs {
    }
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 11
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.j256.ormlite:ormlite-android:4.48'
    compile 'com.j256.ormlite:ormlite-core:4.48'
    compile files('libs/fat.jar')
    compile files('libs/lifesense_ble_v3.2.3.jar')

    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.2.42'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1'
    compile files('libs/realm-0.82.2.jar')
}
```

How to resolve this error?

Comment: I think DefaultReealmModule class exist in multiple jar. remove one of the jar file that is not required

Comment: @AndiGeeky I have included my gradle in the question

Comment: @languageIndependent I removed the multiple jar but giving the same error

Comment: @Corrupt : Check answer if it works or not..!!

Comment: @AndiGeeky Its not working giving the same error

Answer (score 1):

Christian Melchior, developer at Realm, explained in a [GitHub bug](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/1545):

> Are you using library projects that include Realm as well? Then there
>   are some things to be aware of as described here:
>   https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#sharing-schemas

So if you are using a library with realm, make sure not to append `.name("app.realm").setModules(Realm.getDefaultModule(), new MyLibraryModule())` to your Realm builder. The referenced documentation explains this in detail.

Answer (score 0):

Change your dependencies as following :

```
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.j256.ormlite:ormlite-android:4.48'
    compile 'com.j256.ormlite:ormlite-core:4.48'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.2.42'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1'
```

Thank you..!!

Comment: @Corrupt : Add this dependancy -> compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'